# Setting up Selenium 2 on Mac OS X with ChromeDriver

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver

I have used Selenium 2 before  with java and OpenSUSE. Now, am on a Mac and want to set it up for use with Python 2.7 . I have downloaded and unzipped the selenium 2.28 and downloaded ChromeDriver and kept it in in /Users/username/Downloads. And update the path in bash_profile. But, when I run a simple code snippet, like this ,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "Google" in driver.title
driver.close()
```

I just took it from the documentation to test. I get an error like the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_selenium_testing.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.27.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.27.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 64, in start
    and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list                and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

But, chromedriver is on the path. This is what echo $PATH gives me :

```
Other stuff:***/Users/rohitdholakia/Downloads/chromedriver***
```

What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put the executable itself in the PATH instead of the directory containing it.

Try `/Users/rohitdholakia/Downloads` in your PATH.

Comment: AFter adding the Q, I came across another stackoverflow Q and apparently the python bindings have some bug ( maybe resolved by now, dont know). Anyway installed chromedriver by using "brew install" and now it works ! Thanks